# Store response data from multiple axios get requests inside componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, setstate, promise.all

I am using promise.all inside componentdidmount to get response.data from two apis.

```
constructor(){
    super();
       this.state = {
        data: [],
        p1: [],
        p2: []
       };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const [res1, res2] = await Promise.all([
      axios.get(api1),
      axios.get(api2)
    ]);
    this.setState({
      p1: res1.data,
      p2: res2.data
    });
    console.log("this.state.p1" ,this.state.p1)
    console.log("this.state.p2" ,this.state.p2)
  }
```

Sometimes both this.state.p1 and this.state.p2 return correct data but sometimes when I refresh my page this.state.p1 returns data of this.state.p2 and this.state.p2 becomes empty.

Comment: Don't put async on componentDidMount. Create an anonymous function inside it with async and then call it. componentDidMount() { const myAnony = async () => await Promise.all(...); myAnony();

Comment: You cannot use `console.log` immediately  after `setstate`. Since it is `asyc`. Use the console.log in your render, since after the state change, render would be called and you should see the new data in render.

Comment: @Panther Getting the same issue even after using console.log inside render

Comment: @SteveTomlin How do I setState as response.data returned from the apis ? Can you please add a code snippet here, which I can refer to? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ShubhiManral you can bind it like this. myAnony.bind(this)

Comment: @SteveTomlin the issue still exits